# How to prove the following limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $t>0$ be fixed.Show that

> $\hspace{50mm}$
> $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\{\sin \frac{t}{n}+\sin \frac{2t}{n}+\ldots \sin\frac{(n-3)t}{n}\}=\frac{1-\cos t}{t}$

Please give some hints to start the problem.I am totally clueless.

#### NOTE

I have been given a  down-vote.I don't know why.I only wanted some hints to start the problem.Moreover the solution which has been up-voted neither contains any hints nor any justification for  the solution; much to my surprise contains the solution as answer

Comment: You have a typo somewhere; there should be no $n$ in the limiting value.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't there be some $lim$ statement ?

Comment: Hint: this sure looks like a Riemann sum.

Comment: Denominator on the right should be $t$ instead of $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Riemann sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSum.html) $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-3}\frac{1}{n}f(x_k)$, where $x_k=\frac{k}{n}$ and $f(x)=\sin{tx}$. We know, for example from [here](https://www.dawsoncollege.qc.ca/public/72b18975-8251-444e-8af8-224b7df11fb7/programs/disciplines/math/coursesupplements/supplementary_notes_-_riemann_sum.pdf), that by definition of definite integral $$\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n=\int_a^{b} f(x) dx$$
Here lower bound of integral is $a=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$ and the upper is $b=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n-3}{n}=1$.
Finally,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-3}\sin \frac{kt}{n}=\int_{0}^{1}\sin tx dx=-\frac{\cos{tx}}{t}|_0^1=\frac{1-\cos t}{t}.$$

Comment: I am hardly getting any justification why the sum gets reduced to the integral ;how are we getting $x,\text {dx}$ ;sorry I will not be able to accept  the answer

Comment: @ S.Bandopadhaya I hope it will be clarified now.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Noting $\sin x=\Im e^{ix}$, then you can have
$$ \sin \frac{t}{n}+\sin \frac{2t}{n}+\cdots+\sin \frac{(n-3)t}{n}=\Im(e^{\frac{t}{n}}+e^{\frac{2t}{n}}+\cdots+e^{\frac{(n-3)t}{n}}).$$
By using $1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$, you will get the answer.